# Java Filter Infinite loop

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, servlet-filters, infinite-loop

I want to implement a filter to do the authentication, but somehow it is stuck in infinite loop... Any idea appreciated.

```
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    doBeforeProcessing(request, response);

    Throwable problem = null;
    HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(true);
    if(session.getAttribute("userName")!=null&&session.getAttribute("userName")!=(""))
    {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // If an exception is thrown somewhere down the filter chain,
            // we still want to execute our after processing, and then
            // rethrow the problem after that.
            problem = t;
            t.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }else{
        httpResponse.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        return;
    }
```

This code in debug mode just run in infinite times, basicly i want to redirect the user to the login.jsp when he is not logged in.
Any answer appreciated.

Comment: Is this filter also running on the `login.jsp` page?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Anyway i came up with a solution:
"if (uri.indexOf("login.jsp")>-1) {
   chain.doFilter(request, response); // Just continue chain.
   return;
  } "

Comment: Or is there any more elegant way to exclude login.jsp from filtering? I thought someline in the web.xml but as far as i know it is not support this <exclude-url> tag or something like this feature :(

Comment: Then that is definitely the cause of your loop, and you have found the solution to the problem... unfortunately there is no exclusion syntax for filter url-mapping

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here,

```
httpResponse.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

you're sending a **new** HTTP request for the target page instead of using the current request for it. This new HTTP request would of course hit the filter once again if it's been mapped on an overly generic URL pattern, such as `/*`. And the same checks would be performed and it would be redirected again. Etcetera. This is a neverending story.

You need to add an extra check to perform `FilterChain#doFilter()` as well when the currently requested page is the login page.

```
String loginURL = httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";

if (httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL)) || session.getAttribute("userName") != null) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} else {
    httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginURL);
}
```

Note that I also removed the nonsensicial check on the empty string as username (you'd however ensure that *your* code is nowhere setting an empty string as username. Just use `null` to represent a non-logged-in user. Also note that I fixed the redirect URL as well, because it would have failed when the currently requested URL is in a subfolder.

A different alternative is to put all those restricted pages in a common subfolder, such as `/app`, `/secured`, `/restricted`, etc and then map the filter on an URL pattern of `/app/*`, `/secured/*`, `/restricted/*`, etc instead. If you keep the login page outside this folder, then the filter won't be invoked when the login page is been requested.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your filter is running on `login.jsp`, and when the user is not logged in to will repeatedly redirect to itself. Because there is no exclusion syntax on filter `url-pattern` you will need to detect the URL in your filter and omit the redirect if you are already on the `login.jsp` page:

```
    // your auth code
} else {
    String redirect = httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";
    String uri = httpRequest.getRequestURI().toString();
    if (uri.endsWith(redirect)){
        // URI ends with login.jsp, just process the chain
        chain.doFilter();
    } else {
        // not on the login page and not logged in, redirect
        httpResponse.sendRedirect(redirect);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you doublesharp, i voted up your solution (and basicly what we was talking about in the comment section with extra of getContextPaath() and endsWith() functions)... Was hard to accept only one, but BalusC has some new information for me. (and as i saw was faster aswell...) Thanks again doublesharp!

Comment: Always vote in favor of more info and faster execution :)