# How we can use Servlet Filter for sessioncheck?

Tags: java, servlets

I am new in java. am try to use Servlet filters for session check.My code is given below. but i got error while run. please help to correct the error. the error code is

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Cannot forward after response has been committed
type Exception report

message Cannot forward after response has been committed

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

And my code is

my web.xml

```
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sample.wordnik.servlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<filter>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            com.sample.wordnik.filter.SessionFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
            <param-value>login.jsp,signup.jsp</param-value>

        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my Filter class is

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

    private ArrayList<String> urlList;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        String url = request.getServletPath();
        boolean allowedRequest = false;

        if(urlList.contains(url)) {
            allowedRequest = true;
        }

        if (!allowedRequest) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (null == session) {
                response.sendRedirect("login");
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        String urls = config.getInitParameter("avoid-urls");
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls, ",");

               urlList = new ArrayList<String>();


        while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
            urlList.add(token.nextToken());

        }
    }
}
```

And My LoginServlet is

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
}
```

Comment: @Balusc that was not the answer for this question. just checkout this question and answer for it

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you had already redirected the user on `login page` for invalid session using `response.sendRedirect("login")`. However you had also tried to continue with request chain after redirect `chain.doFilter(req, res)`.

Try using `return` keyword here:

```
if (null == session) {
    response.sendRedirect("login");
    return; // added
}
```

Comment: error change to        'This webpage has a redirect loop'

Comment: @AjmalMuhammad Is this Only chrome behavior or IE/firefox also show similar behavior?

Comment: firefox shows this error "The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: That's a different problem which is answered among others here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114743/java-filter-infinite-loop/